# Does Google Tag Manager Custom HTML accept HTML5?

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I just put in a simple html code.

```
<header><p>hello</p></header>
```

Gives the invalid HTML, CSS or script error and can't publish.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "hello" is not HTML code...? We're going to need to see some markup code...

Comment: SO converted my html doh! sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the newer elements and attributes have not yet been whitelisted for the Custom HTML tag in GTM.  Header is one of them.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, is there documentation on this or just your experience is the same as mine?